# Draw a chart line in Android

Tags: android, charts

What would be a simple example of drawing a plot in Android with a CHART LINE using a JAR file (and the JAR file itself)?

I want to draw a CHART LINE, not chart pie nor chart bar, and I want to do this by importing a JAR file into my application.

I have found some examples of JAR file on the Internet, but these don't have example of usage, or are way too complicated.

I just want a simple plot, and it doesn't have too be that nice (neither ugly;)))

The JAR file must be free!

EDIT:

Something like `http://writerbay.net/?p=401`, but not this one :D I can't use it - I have my reasons!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in *[Any good graphing packages for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752)* for lots of charting packages with links to each one. Each one of the links has examples of how to use it. I've used [AChartEngine](http://www.achartengine.org/index.html), and it was easy enough.

See *[svn/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/AverageTemperatureChart.jav](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/AverageTemperatureChart.java)* for a simple example of a line chart  - this example has 4 lines, but you could do one or whatever.

Comment: The second example if full of errors....could u help me a little bit cause I can't manage...for the second one should I create an activity an call this from an activity?:-S

Comment: Or this one:http://android.arnodenhond.com/graphview......it has no jar included in it.....but it has an undertandble example:P

Comment: the example is not full of errors - in fact it is the exact code the author used in the demo included in the download.  In that case, he is using an activity to hold the graph. Without seeing what you attempted, i  cant really help.  Perhaps you should post another question with your sample code for that specific issue.

Comment: @jkhouw Could U please take a look in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217371/draw-a-graph-in-android

Comment: We can see you are. Just take a closer look at the demo source code and you will eventually understand it rather that saying it is full of errors. Just a hint: it is based on some basic OOP principles like: inheritance, polymorphism,...